# Log file size exceeds issue in Log4net

Tags: log4net

I'm using Log4Net in my build.
When Log size is exceeds the max size ,it will create the another file with the name " TestFile.2018-10-06.2018-10-06.xml" . But when i'm trying to open the logs (**Both Duplicate and Main Log file**) it throws the Exception as "**Exception of type System.Outofmemoryexception was thrown**.How to handle the Error and how can i check my logs from those two Logs ?.Please suggest me .I have been struggling from 2 days with this error .Any Suggest answer will be appreciated.

Pavan G.